# Using Tasks to process a large input file

Tags: .net, vb.net, task-parallel-library

Updated 14-Nov-2016, as I see some answers (which are very much appreciated) are asking for more details...

Language: `VB.Net / Framework: 4.5`

Dear TPL experts, I am new to the Task Processing Library (TPL) and would appreciate any help with the following:

I need to process a large file (several hundred thousand records).  Each record is a tab delimited record with up to 4 fields.

For each record read, I need to extract the fields and the invoke an asnyc task to process those fields.

Obviously, I will need to throttle the process by only allowing up to `10` records to be processed at a time, that is, start a maximum of `10` tasks at once.

For example, if I read the first `10` records, then `10` tasks will be started.  If **any** one of tasks finishes, I read the next record and start another task, and so on until end of file. Basically, I want to optimize the number of records I can read and process at the same time.

So far, this is what I have come up with:

```
   rec_list = New StreamReaderEnumerable( file_spec )

   For each rec In rec_list 

      task_list.Add( Task.Run( Async Function()
                                   Return Await task_func( rec )
                               End Function
                              )
                   )

      If ( task_list.Count >= 10 ) Then

         Task.WhenAll( task_list )

         task_list.Clear()

      End If

   Next
```

The "StreamReaderEnumerable" class is used to return one record from the file at a time (as an Enumerable source) and I am then adding a Task to a list in order process 10 tasks at a time.

There is no need to maintain any type of order as each Task may finish at any time -- I am just trying to increase the efficiency of processing records greater than one at a time.

Problem is, I am currently waiting for all 10 of the tasks to finish before I can continue.  It would be nice to optimize this further.

I guess what I am looking for is a ForEachAsync type of enumerator -- but haven't found any clear examples yet ...

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Sound like the perfect job for [TPL Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) Would write up a example with it, but I don't know vb that well to get the syntax right.

Comment: *What* kind of work are you trying to perform? Using a regular expression instead of string splits can easily 10x speed improvements because it *doesn't* generate/cleanup temporary strings. These temporary strings add up *very* quickly when dealing with large files

Comment: And memory usage can go from 2GB to 50-100MB, depending on what you do. Allocating and cleaning 1.9 GB of small strings requires a *lot* of CPU

Comment: Looking for a solution using existing .Net Framework -- the TPL dataflow namespace is not distributed with 4.5, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. You should take a look for [`BlockingCollection` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997306.aspx). You can limit the size of the collection by `10`, create a consumer task, which will add a line to the collection, and some producer tasks, which will take a line from the collection until the end of the file. Something like this:

   ```
   var numbers = new BlockingCollection<string>(10);
   // this task should be refactored to accept a method
   Task.Run(() =>
   {
       while (!lines.IsCompleted)
       {
           try
           {
               var line = lines.Take();
               // do stuff here
           }
           catch (InvalidOperationException)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("Adding was completed!");
               break;
           }
       }
       Console.WriteLine("No more lines to take.");
   });

   // A simple blocking producer with no cancellation.
   Task.Run(() =>
   {
       while (!END_OF_FILE_CHECK)
       {
           // this method will block until you have less than 10 lines in a collection
           lines.Add(line);
       }
       lines.CompleteAdding();
   });
   ```

   Both tasks should be created with [`LongRunning` flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions.aspx), as this will dedicate a thread for all of them:

   > Specifies that a task will be a long-running, coarse-grained operation involving fewer, larger components than fine-grained systems. It provides a hint to the `TaskScheduler` that oversubscription may be warranted. Oversubscription lets you create more threads than the available number of hardware threads. It also provides a hint to the task scheduler that an additional thread might be required for the task so that it does not block the forward progress of other threads or work items on the local thread-pool queue.
2. Other approach, as @ScottChamberlain suggested, is to use the same Producer/Consumer pattern with a `TPL Dataflow` with limited degree of parallelism, something like this:

   ```
   var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<string>(
       line =>
       {
           // do stuff here   
       },
       // No more than 10 lines simultaneosly
       new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
       {
           MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
       });

   while (!END_OF_FILE_CHECK)
   {
       workerBlock.Post(line);
   }
   workerBlock.Complete();

   // Wait for all messages to propagate through the network.
   workerBlock.Completion.Wait();
   ```

   You also can introduce some producer block [like here in tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601.aspx), and add some other block linked to the `worker` to handle it's results.

Comment: A regular expression can search and extract data from a big log file as fast as 10+ tasks that perform string manipulations. That's because it avoids generating temporary strings until required, reducing allocations and cleanups. Performing an inefficient operation in parallel can easily result in *slower* execution

Comment: As OP said, that he must handle every line, the string still be read, and the large file could be read in a streaming fashion, line by line, and there would not be non-required temporary strings

Comment: That's not correct. *How* is the line string processed? *That's* what's taking a lot of time, not reading the file (which isn't addressed here at all BTW). Is string splitting used to extract individual fields? That's N temporary strings per line. A regex match though contains only indexes to matches. Combined with named groups this means that you only need to extract values for actual matches

Comment: Ok then, still approaches I've wrote about works - a collection of the results of the regex still can be handled with `Dataflow` or `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, no. The first one processes a single line at a time, not 10. It uses a single Task, ie a single thread. It could be an ActionBlock with DOP=1. The second does, but it doesn't handle the stuff that matters, ie reading the lines and processing them. It doesn't throttle either, so the entire file will end up in the input buffer

Comment: Regex cannot be used (sorry, I updated my OP to indicate what is happening).  Basically, the line read contains parameters that are used for another Async function call.  The BlockingCollection class appears to be something that would work in this case -- will investigate.  Thanks again to everyone for the comments.